# How to use Barcode Scanner With DataTables Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatable, datatables

I have a POS System With Laravel and i use barcode scanner for products

i have the following products DataTable with one Pagelength DataTable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKf5n.png)

i want to hit the green button and clear textbox after barcode scan

it is possible ?

Comment: Do you know/can find JS code that executes when green button has been clicked?

Comment: i have a JS Code that executes when the green button has been clicked 

the item will be added to cart

Comment: In next line of the same function clear the field. `document.getElementById("example-id").value = ''`. Instead of `example-id` you need to use search field HTML id.